# How to examine the value of a cell in a pcolor plot using the data cursor?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a MATLAB `pcolor` plot.  Say something like this:

```
ixx = 1:10;
ixy = 2:2:25;
[x,y] = meshgrid(ixx, ixy);
pcolor(ixx, ixy, x+y)
```

When I use the data cursor, I don't get the value of the height of the cell, just the locations of the boundary of the cell:

[image: example]

Is there a way to force the cell value to appear in this plot? The associated cell should have value `23`, not `z = 0`.

Note: In my real example, my axes are not uniform, so `pcolor` is required here (as opposed to moving to `imagesc` or similar, which does properly handle the data cursor).

Note: `pcolor` "hides" the top row and right most column of data.  [Not directly relevant to the question, but an important aspect of `pcolor`]

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161501/matlab-scatter-with-tooltip-showing-other-kinds-of-data-and-connecting-points-wi/44175176#44175176) on customizing the data shown in the tooltip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the handle of [**`pcolor`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) to modify `ZData` i.e.

```
ph = pcolor(ixx, ixy, x+y);
ph.ZData = ph.CData;    % or   set(ph, 'ZData', get(ph,'CData'));
```

**Result:**

[image: result]